How can I grant third-party users the Email Editor and Android Management API User roles in the GCP console?onsole?
i have successfully created the Mobile Device Management application with the help of GCP Console project using Node.js. Now, I want to grant access to the role when third-party users want to join MDM application.
Here is the code I have tried:
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const auth = require('./auth'); // Assuming you have auth setup properly

const iam = google.iam('v1');

// Function to grant IAM roles to users
const grantIAMRoles = async (projectId, userEmails) => {
    const resource = {
        resource: {
            policy: {
                bindings: [
                    {
                        role: 'roles/editor',
                        members: userEmails.map(email => `user:${email}`) // Assigning 'Editor' role
                    },
                    {
                        role: 'roles/androidmanagement.user',
                        members: userEmails.map(email => `user:${email}`) // Assigning 'Android Management User' role
                    }
                    // Add more roles if needed
                ]
            }
        },
        auth: auth // Assuming you have authentication set up properly
    };

    try {
        const response = await iam.projects.setIamPolicy({
            resource: `projects/${projectId}`,
            requestBody: resource
        });
        console.log('IAM roles granted successfully:', response.data);
        return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error granting IAM roles:', error);
        throw error;
    }
};

// Usage example
const projectId = 'your-project-id';
const userEmails = ['user1@example.com', 'user2@example.com']; // List of user emails

grantIAMRoles(projectId, userEmails)
    .then(() => {
        console.log('IAM roles granted successfully for users:', userEmails);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error('Failed to grant IAM roles:', err);
    });

I received the error of

Error granting IAM roles: Error: Request contains an invalid argument.

i referred  the link here
Can anyone suggest a solution to the error I'm facing!..
